# Hive table exclusive lock

Tags: hive

How can I remove exclusive lock from my Hive table.Table is external table.
I have tried setting hive.support.concurrency to true, but still when I am dropping the table it goes into exclusive lock. 
In the documentation it says "Set to true to support INSERT ... VALUES, UPDATE, and DELETE transactions (Hive 0.14.0 and later)."

So should I set it to true or false, I have tried with both setting, but still drop query is locked.

Comment: Pls show your hive query. It seems that you use delete  query in hive?

Comment: @pensz drop table maineventslog;

Comment: `show locks maineventslog `  to find out who is using the table.